# Getting jack to work on Ubuntu

Tags: jack

I am having an issue getting Jack to work.

I do not know what outputs (listed under `system/plaback[1-8]` to use but I have patched to all of them and hear nothing.

Is there a way to test audio or verify that my system is configured correctly?

[image: my setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I had pulseaudio running at the same time as JACK on the same sound card.

Pulseaudio and JACK can't run on the same sound card at the same time.

[This link fixed my problem](http://jackaudio.org/faq/pulseaudio_and_jack.html#option-4-suspend-pulseaudio-while-jack-is-running)